# POST with unique name as a variable

Tags: php, variables, post

Okay so I have this page with a form where you can select a lot of stuff that is then send by POST to the next stage - The name field is tilbehor_ and then ther id from the db. - examble "tilbehor_23".

Now on the next page I need to make them into a variable so I can call on ther value later.

Example.
tilbehor_11, tilbehor_34 and tilbehor_65 are send by POST to the next page, and I needd to show ther value on the page somwere by the use of a variable

How would i do that?

Comment: will you give some more details?

Comment: you can do it in either way:- 1. before sending them to next page assign them to variables and then send. 2- when you are on your second page and fetching $_POST then only assign values to variables and use them.

Comment: Have you done any research before posting this on SO?

Comment: What else detail do you need?. There is also a lot of other things send by POST

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    // $key is now 'tilbehor_23' and $val is its value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value'";
     echo $_POST['tilbehor_'.$value];
    }
```

The above will display all the data which is posted. and you just check what is coming and what you want to display.

Comment: few second delay. ha ha

Comment: And how would I get that to work on only things that is posted with the tilbehor_.. This will effect all other things send by POST right?

Comment: in this case if you have element name as tilbehor just check as 
foreach($_POST['tilbeho']  as $key => $value) {
      echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value'";
    }

Comment: that will only display the value of anything posted with the name "tilbehor" i need to have the value of "tilbehor_22", "tilbehor_9", "tilbehor_78" made into a variable so i can display it on the page. But the number in "tilbehor_" may vary from 1 to 999,,

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/m498t434/

i put up the code, and some js that affects the code. 

Where my problem is, is in the first echo. You can see that it gets the name "tilbehor_' . $row['t_id'] . '" and so the name that is sendt by post is (examble) tilbehor_23. It is a quantity box.. Im am trying to get the quantity on the next page... it it makes any sense?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a fixed `key` (e.g. "tilbehor") and pass a variable `value` that can be easily read and processed?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say a POST variable 'tilbehor_34' has a value of '1'. When you do this:

```
$key = 'tilbehor_34';
$$key = $_POST['tilbehor_34'];
```

The variable $tilbehor_34 will now have a value of '1'

Comment: I know how to get tilbehor_34 to a variable. But the number in the name may range from 1 to 999.. So i cant really have 999 variables defined like that :/